# how to fix flask login remember me is not working

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms, flask-login

**Html code**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" checked class="custom-control-input" id="remember_me">
<label class="custom-control-label" for="remember_me">Remember me</label>
```

**Below is the route function**

```
@app.route('/admin_login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def admin_login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        remember_me = request.form['remember_me']


        admin = Admin.query.filter_by(username=username).first()
        if admin is None or not admin.check_password(password):
            flash('Invild password or username!')
            return redirect(url_for('admin_login'))

        

        login_user(admin, remember=remember_me)
        flash('Logged in successfully.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

    return render_template('login.html', title='Login')
```

**if I can't check the checkbox I got the following error**

***I'm tried to solve this error I need help!!!***

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
KeyError: 'remember_me'
```

Answer (score 0):

When checkbox is unchecked, returned value for remember_me is `None`. To handle this, instead of:
`remember_me = request.form['remember_me']`

Use:
`remember_me = request.form.get('remember_me')`